# How I can make a list view to send touch events to the items in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I need to implement custom elements in a list view.

Each list element has more custom elements inside that need to receive the touch events. The problem is that I only receive `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and I want to receive `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

Is there a solution to prevent the list from stealing the touch events?

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. If you mean a list view with custom clickable elements try this tutorial, was very helpful to me, [Android Hive - custom ListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

You have just to implement:

```
ListView list;

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //your code here

     }
 });
```

Finally if you want to try something different take a look also at this [library](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

Comment: The OP is talking about touch events that you receive from a touchelistener. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html. You provide a listener for tapping on a row. That does not contain motionevents.